# Fill down value with Dax in PowerBI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

Can you help me on this issue,

I want to fill down OB and EB column, by the nearest value, which is not blank().

Example:
OB in Jul, Aug, Sep = 6.187.304
also with EB in Jul, Aug, Sep = 6.187.304
(in red part)

With the condition value in total not change (green).

[Check this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAgOU.png)

Here are the current DAX codes:

```
AP_OB = 
var min_date =  min(dim_date[Date])
var OB = CALCULATE(SUM(ap[Ending balance]),PREVIOUSMONTH(dim_date[Date]))
var OB_max = CALCULATE(max(ap[begining_balance]),FILTER(ap,ap[date] <= min_date))
return
if(month(min_date) > MIN(dim_date[month]), OB_max, OB)
```

```
AP_EB = 
var tesst =  min(dim_date[Date])
var tesst_2 =  max(dim_date[Date])
var OB_test = CALCULATE(SUM(ap[Ending balance]),FILTER(ap,'ap'[Month] =MONTH(tesst_2)))

Var max_date_of_ap = CALCULATE(MAX(ap[date]),REMOVEFILTERS(ap))
Var eb_of_max_date = CALCULATE(sum(ap[Ending balance]),FILTER(ap,ap[date] = max_date_of_ap))
var min_dim_date = MIN(dim_date[Date])

return
if(if(month(tesst) > MIN(dim_date[month]), BLANK(), OB_test)=BLANK(),eb_of_max_date,if(month(tesst) > MIN(dim_date[month]), BLANK(), OB_test))
```

Thank you for your helps!

Best regards.

Comment: Without knowing 100% what your data means, I'm not sure how to answer, but the normal way to do a fill down (as long as you're not trying to sum that column!) is to do it in PowerQuery.  The values will fill down to blank "cells" only.